# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.NoSuchDriverException in eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, eclipse

Facing the below error while running selenium java project in eclipse

```java
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.NoSuchDriverException: chromedriver located at C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Desktop\chromedriver.exe, but invalid
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/
Build info: version: '4.15.0', revision: '1d14b5521b'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 11', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '20'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverFinder.getPath(DriverFinder.java:13)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.generateExecutor(ChromeDriver.java:100)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:89)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:84)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:52)
    at OpenGoogle.main(OpenGoogle.java:8)
```

Comment: What is the code in question that produces this error?

Comment: import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class OpenGoogle {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
   System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\hp\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");
  WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");
 }
}